# Application for "button" Other is not an accessory and is not frontmost

Tags: xctest

I have an xcuitest. But my tests fails often with the message
Application for "button" Other is not an accessory and is not frontmost

What could be the reason.

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your "button" is actually a button type. To make sure, put a breakpoint and type "po XCUIApplication()" in your xcode console.

Then find your element in the tree and check the type of your element.

You can also use the method "waitForElementToAppear" to make sure that your element is rendered and in frontmost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try that out and will update